# Highlight Text in HTML page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to user `filter` function to highlight a search text.
Here is the view.

[image]

Of course I used `ion-search` of ionic (version 3).

As you could see, I succeeded to parse the DOM elements and `scrollIntoView` of the `p` tag that contains the searched text (currently, I'm restricting to only `p` tags).

**In the HTML page I inserted that:**

```
<!-- Search -->
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="myInput" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
(ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" placeholder="Search..." debounce=500>
</ion-searchbar>
```

**Here is the method that listens to keyup in search bar:**

```
  onInput(ev) {
    let searchedText = ev.target.value;
    if (searchedText && searchedText.trim() != '') {
      this.pTagsArray = Array.from(this.content.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('p'));
      this.pTagsArray = this.pTagsArray.filter((item) => {
        if (item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(searchedText.toLowerCase())) {
          item.scrollIntoView();
          this.heighlight(item, searchedText);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })
    }
  }
```

And here:

```
  heighlight(pTag: any, text: any) {
    var r = pTag.innerHTML.replace(text, '<span style="color:red">' + text + '</span>');
    console.log(r);
  }
```

Very important note, is that in the console I see the insertion of the new `span` but the page is not rendered, since I see in the console of chrome :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace method does not change the initial data. You can do like this:

```
pTag.innerHTML = r;
```

Comment: Quite simple :)